SQLAlchemy query error when column type FBTEXT exists
Table:
...
name BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT(0),
Class generated:
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = (
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('userid', name='pk_userid'),
    )
name = mapped_column(FBTEXT(1, 'NONE', 'NONE'))

Query:
query_result = (
       fb_session.query(Users)
).all()


value = bytes(value)
^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string argument without an encoding


it was generated  by sqlacodegen_v2 --tables users firebird+fdb://sysdb....

I don't have a firebird setup, but I would guess that the arguments to FBTEXT should be set to something appropriate.  The signature is FBTEXT(segment, charset, collation) so perhaps consider experimenting with setting charset and collation to "UTF-8" (in a test environment).

If you define a column as having encoding NONE, then it means it has no known encoding, so in that sense, the error makes sense. How is the table defined?

I'm using pycharm ide to connect to firebird
name BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT(0)

I've found a workaround to fix this issue:
I changed the column type FBTEXT to FBVARCHAR
name = mapped_column(FBVARCHAR(100, 'NONE', 'NONE'))
To find the column length you can use this query:
select max(char_length(name)) from users
